# Cancel multi-threading Tasks including running .dll

Tags: c#, excel, asynchronous, com, task

I have 2 different Tasks that are launched synchronously. One of them is a method in which I call .dll for creating COM object (writing Excel file). When I terminate both tasks, Excel file is still in use, so I can't delete It. This is how I call both Tasks:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancel_1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
private CancellationTokenSource cancel_2 = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        cancel_1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task_1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork1(), cancel_1.Token);

        //2nd task
        cancel_2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task_2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoExcelWork(), cancel_2.Token);
    }
```

Then I try to cancel both tasks in form_closing:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   //Cancel all running processes
   cancel_1.Cancel();
   cancel_2.Cancel();

   // I've also set a variable for check if Task_2 is running and try to clear COM 
   // object with clearing GC(), but It's not working
   if (excel_running)
   {
       GC.Collect();
       GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
       GC.Collect();
       GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

       string filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop).ToString() + @"\" + "sample.xlsx";
       File.Delete(filename)

   }
}
```

However, that is not terminating process that was launched by .dll for writing Excel file. I noticed that running proccess in background is "COM surrogate", so as you see I tried with cleaning GC() in 2 cycles but file is still in use.

My code for method in thread is something like this:

```
public void DoExcelWork()
{
    try
    {
        using (var con = new OracleConnection(conn_string))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("myprocedure"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("par1", OracleDbType.NVarchar2) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = SQL_string });

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("result", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                //Here is the call of .dll             
                Export export_xml = new Export();
                export_xml.Save_to_Excel(cmd);

                excel_running = false;

                if (cancel_2.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                   cmd.Cancel();
                   return;
                }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "in " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

**My question is - how to properly cancel background processes, so that It will close even running .dll ?**

Comment: You're using cancellation source wrong. You need to periodically check the cancellation state and if cancel has been requested you need to handle that yourself. Does excel class have a cancel method that you can call?

Comment: @the.Doc, sorry, I forgot to paste how I check requested cancellation in DoExcelWork(), I edited now. As for .dll - no I don't have any cancel method. Should I add It & how ?

Comment: Is save_to_excel a blocking call? What is it doing internally that can be cancelled, other than the oracle cmd?

Comment: @the.Doc, nothing else can be cancelled internally. "cmd" is being passed to .dll, then all the logic is done from there - It fetches data from DB and writes to Excel file.  Should I add token parameter in **save_to_excel**, and add "**token.IsCancellationRequested etc.**" inside .dll and close everything there, would that work ?

Comment: Is it possible to move your code from the Office COM Interop to the more modern [Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) that microsoft provides for manipulating office files that use the ".xlsx" extension? That may help solve a lot of your problems because it the Open XML SDK does not need to open a instance of Excel, it can manipulate the files directly.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I allready have exactly that :)... Furthermore, I think I allready fixed problem via logic that I wrote in my last comment, but I'm still running some tests. Currently Im getting some errors in Console when I cancel tasks, but Excel file does get deleted. I will post answer as soon as I finish :)

Comment: I've edited my question. Task is closed, but I'm still receiving some error while doing that.

Comment: Nevermind , I fixed everything now. A lot had to be done though.

Comment: @the.Doc, thanks for commenting, your questions made me think in right direction.

Comment: It is a classic threading race bug.  Cancel() is not enough, you have to wait until the tasks actually stop running.  Only way to be sure that GC.Collect() can actually release the interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to re-organize DoExcelWork() method to accept additional parameter for CancellationToken, and then within method with a call of "token.IsCancellationRequested" close all objects that were creating Excel file.